# getting an exception while using DirectoryServices object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, active-directory

I am using Active Directory to authenticate a user logging into an ASP.NET web site on a corporate intranet. I am getting an error of "handle is invalid" on the following line of code:

```
Dim entry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(path, domainAndUsername, Password)
```

Here is my code I am using to authenticate. 
    Dim entry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(path, domainAndUsername, Password)

```
    Try
        'Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.          

        Dim obj As Object = entry.NativeObject
        Dim search As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(entry)

        search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" & Username & ")"
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn")
        Dim result As SearchResult = search.FindOne()

        If (result Is Nothing) Then
            Return False
        End If

        'Update the new path to the user in the directory.
        '_path = result.Path
        '_filterAttribute = CType(result.Properties("cn")(0), String)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Error authenticating user. " & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

How do I track down this exception? Visual Studio says it is a CryptographicException

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://forums.asp.net/t/1729360.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on .NET 3.5.... and thinking the code translates well to VB you could use built-in method.

```
public bool isValidUser(string password,string username,string domain)
        {
            var isValid = false;
            using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
            {
                isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
            }
            return isValid;
        }
```

I know it does not answer question as such, but could avoid getting the exception in the first place